# AWS SES and PHP - sending limits?

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to send email through the Codeigniter email functionality and I'm using my aws ses credentials. The from address has been verified but it still throws the following error. I am not on a production package. And my max sending rate is 1 per second. The verified email is good to send email the first few times(sending around 10 emails), after which I get the error below. I've tried it across different days just to see if the sending rate would get corrected, but the error persists.

```
"email":"220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-123456789\r\n<br \/><pre>hello: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com\r\n250-8BITMIME\r\n250-SIZE 10485760\r\n250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\r\n250 Ok\r\n<\/pre><pre>from: 250 Ok\r\n<\/pre><pre>to: 250 Ok\r\n<\/pre><pre>data: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n<\/pre>554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.\r\n<br \/>The following SMTP error was encountered: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.\r\n<br \/>Unable to send email using PHP SMTP.  Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.<br \/><pre>User-Agent: CodeIgniter\r\nDate: Wed, 27 Feb 2013 18:22:30 +0100\r\nFrom: \"Us\" <verified from address>\r\nReturn-Path: <verified from address>\r\nTo: test@gmail.com\r\nSubject: =?utf-8?Q?Notification?=\r\nReply-To: \"verified from address\" <verified from address>\r\nX-Sender: verified from address\r\nX-Mailer: CodeIgniter\r\nX-Priority: 3 (Normal)\r\nMessage-ID: <512e40d65c149@domain.com>\r\nMime-Version: 1.0\r\n\n\nContent-Type: text\/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\nHello Sara\r\n\r\nPlease find the url below:\r\n\r\n http:\/\/192.168.0.36\/verify_agent\/10\/406387e745014f3b4f856\r\n\r\n\r\nThank you,\r\nFrom person\r\n<\/pre>"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=85895

Comment: It does not say its blacklisted. However, if it does help I only have the sandbox access. And the dashboard it says "With sandbox access, you can only send email to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator and to email addresses that you have verified. As with production access, you can only send email from verified email addresses." Does that mean my to addresses also need to be verified?

Comment: If you want to send as "something@google.com", that email address has to be verified, yes, in order for you to send mail as that address.

Comment: The sender email address is verified. But do the recipient email addresses have to be verified too? Like I said earlier, the verified from email address works well for the first couple of times after which it fails.

Comment: I think I just found the cause. With sandbox access, the to and from email addresses must be verified addresses. Everything went through fine this time!

Comment: @softie Please let me know if you find any solution on that problem, because i face same problem